# SQL Join on multiple columns of a row

Tags: sql, join

I have the following table IDDetails:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
1   2   3
1   5   7 and so on
```

I want to link each ID of the row with a name from the Names table:

```
ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
5  E
7  G
```

The output should have 6 columns like :

```
ID1 Name1 ID2 Name2 ID3 Name3
1   A     2   B     3   C
1   A     5   E     7   G
```

The operation should have minimum joins with limited cost.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show some work with justification, explain about the first place you get stuck & ask a specific question about it. Give the name & edition of an information modeling & database design textbook you are following & refer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. Note that you have to `JOIN` the `Names` table 3 times to get the three different names for each row.

```
SELECT i.ID1, n1.Name AS Name1,
       i.ID2, n2.Name AS Name2,
       i.ID3, n3.Name AS Name3
FROM IDDetails i
JOIN Names n1 on n1.ID = i.ID1
JOIN Names n2 on n2.ID = i.ID2
JOIN Names n3 on n3.ID = i.ID3
```

Output:

```
ID1     Name1   ID2     Name2   ID3     Name3
1       A       2       B       3       C
1       A       5       E       7       G
```

**Update**

Here is a query without `JOIN`s, as requested in the edit after the original post:

```
SELECT i.ID1, (SELECT Name FROM Names n WHERE n.ID = i.ID1) AS Name1,
       i.ID2, (SELECT Name FROM Names n WHERE n.ID = i.ID2) AS Name2,
       i.ID3, (SELECT Name FROM Names n WHERE n.ID = i.ID3) AS Name3
FROM IDDetails i
```

Output:

```
ID1     Name1   ID2     Name2   ID3     Name3
1       A       2       B       3       C
1       A       5       E       7       G
```

[SQLFiddle Demo of both queries](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f15f6f/2)